# mystery RemotingException raised when changing Platform Target to Any CPU

Tags: c#

I'm going to assume my installed version of .NET is foobared, but thought I would ask anyways as this makes no sense.

1. Create a new C# Console Application
2. Change Platform Target to Any CPU
3. Run
4. See a RemotingException be raised!?!

   ```
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'e:\dev\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe'
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
   The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x1494) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
   The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x12f0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
   'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'e:\dev\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe', Symbols loaded.
   A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
   An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

   Additional information: The async result object is null or of an unexpected type.
   ```

   > mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Message reqMsg, bool bProxyCase) + 0x2d0 bytes 
   >       mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(object NotUsed, ref System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData msgData) + 0x191 bytes
   >       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.get() + 0x1d2 bytes 
   >       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ApplyBoundsConstraints(int suggestedX, int suggestedY, int proposedWidth, int proposedHeight) + 0x12a bytes
   >       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.FillInCreateParamsStartPosition(System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) + 0x4ab bytes
   >       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateParams.get() + 0x153 bytes 
   >       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle() + 0x146 bytes
   >       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle() + 0x2ad bytes 
   >       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Handle.get() + 0x68 bytes 
   >       Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunParkingWindowThread() + 0xbd bytes
   >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) + 0xdc bytes
   >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x3b bytes
   >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x4d bytes
   >       [Native to Managed Transition]

Comment: Show the relevant code please.

Comment: It is a fresh console application. I did not change one line. The exception is raised before Program.Main() is called.

Comment: So, you do not have any remoting code? If so, that is strange. Try running it without using the 'hosting process' (option in project properties/debug).

Comment: I have absolutely no remoting code. I have no code at all besides Program.Main(). Hmmm, seems that a full reboot has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the execution path being too long. If it is over 127 character while executing as 64bit it goes pop. This is a .net 4 issue as far as im aware and the only thing that I've seen fix it is the make the entry assembly output name shorter. IMO, this is a rubbish fix and needs addressing by MS.

Edit: Solutions -
Run as x86,
or shorten project / user name

Comment: Where did you hear this? I haven't been able to find more information on this issue other than from this post.

Comment: I read it on SO in another stack but couldn't find it again to reference in this answer. Sorry about that. It was an ambiguous answer with no reason but it worked for me.

Similarly, my colleague has a very long surname and that caused the file name to be too long which also broke at runtime - the solution? Change the user account name or execute as x86. Deployed builds work fine afaik.

Have you had any luck @BasedAsFunk?